# Magento 2: Custom product attribute in order confirmation email

Tags: php, magento, attributes, magento2

I have to try to add custom attributes to the order confirmation email. For instance, I have added the following code to fetch custom product attributes created in Magento 2 and has value as well within the product information.

```
    <p class="sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()) : ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option) : ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?= $block->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd>
                <?= /* @noEscape */  nl2br($block->escapeHtml($option['value'])) ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p class="sku">manual</p> <!-- Not showing -->
    <p class="msg"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('msg') ?>: <?= $status_new = $_item->product()->getAttributeText('status') ?></p> <!-- Not showing -->
```

I have added

```
 <!-- Not showing -->
```

in code above, so you can see where I have made customization on the order confirmation email. However, making changes to this file does not show a new custom attribute even the custom text I have added on the email template.

I have tried making changes to

```
 \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml
```

and also copied this template into the front-end custom template as following

```
 \app\design\frontend\master\version2\Magento_Sales\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml
```

No changes are effected, still showing the order confirmation with the same template, not sure from where it is being loaded.

Tried to run deploy content and cleared the cache as well, nothing is effecting the changes.

Comment: above code working with custom attribute type dropdown, but not with text  type?

Comment: Is the override template working? Are the changes partly visible?